# reimport missing data after migration is done

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

i did data import to migrate all my products by after migration i found few order or new customer.

now i do not want to redo database reset and redo migration is there way to migrate just missing one or way that migration will start from last migrated data anything to solve rework

Comment: Can you tell me which method or tool you used to migration of data?

Comment: i am using magento 2 data import